# Javascript -Trim Array of URL's to Root Domain

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am developing a chrome extension that can copy the urls of all tabs in a browser. The problem is i can only trim one url in all the array. Is there a way i can output all the root domain in the popup?thanks in advance

example of the tabs url

```
youtube.com/asdwea/asdsa
google.com/asdwew
facebook.com/qwea/asd
```

the result for the popup should be

```
youtube.com
google.com
facebook.com
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id="count"> all</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, getAllOpenWindows);
function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {

  var tabs = [];
  for (var i in winData) {
    if (winData[i].focused === true) {
        var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
        var totTabs = winTabs.length;
        for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
          tabs.push(winTabs[j].url+ "</br>");

        }
        var domain = tabs[1].replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
    }

  }
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = tabs.length;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = domain;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {

  var tabs = [];
  for (var i in winData) {
    if (winData[i].focused === true) {
        var domainStr = "";
        var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
        var totTabs = winTabs.length;
        for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
          var str = winTabs[j].url+ "</br>";
          tabs.push(str);
          domainStr += str;
        }
        domainStr = domainStr.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = tabs.length;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = domainStr;

}
```

I think what you need is concat all strings, which is `domainStr` here.
As your question is not related to `split` function, I did not check whether `.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];` works.

Comment: example the new tabs url are
google.com/asdasds
youtube.com/asdaeqweqw/asdas
facebook.com/ asdwqe/asda

what i want is the result will be
google.com
youtube.com
facebook.com

Comment: Yes. I know what you want to do. But I guess you did not want to ask something about it, so I did not give my suggestion. If you need, I recommend something like
`
const urlStr = "aurl https:// ...";

const urlObj = new URL(urlStr );

console.log(urlObj.host);
console.log(urlObj.hostname);
`
This piece of code should be in the `j<totTabs` loop.